# Audio crackle when rendered (VSE)

Tags: rendering, video-sequence-editor, audio

The audio's fine during playback, but when rendered, it's common to see crackles (that you can 'repair' in Audacity). The crackling appears when I add audio strips. When an audio strip starts or ends, it's possible to have a max volume crackle in the rendered version.

I render my videos with mp3 audio format, because that's the only one that doesn't crash and exit the whole Blender during rendering.

Comment: Try changing the sample amount for more accuracy when exporting.

Comment: What do you mean? Sample rate? So I have to change the sample rate of every single audio file? Change to what? To the rate of the project? Where is the sample rate in the project? Min, max, packet, bitrate...?

Comment: Its a value to set at audio only render/mixdown